# How do I redirect all subdomain requests to primary domain in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect all subdomain requests to be redirected to my primary domain in my htaccess. I need it to also include some sort of wildcard redirect.

e.g. washington.mysite.com/ redirect to mysite.com/washington

but I need to to also redirect any old url on the subdomain to mysite.com/washington

e.g. washington.mysite.com/category.aspx?washington-attractions&CatID=17 redirect to my-site.com/washington

This is my code so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^washington\.mysite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.washington\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/washington/$1" [R=301,L]
```

However it still appends the old URL to the new one

e.g. washington.mysite.com/category.aspx?washington-attractions&CatID=17 redirects to my-site.com/washington/category.aspx?washington-attractions&CatID=17

Basically I need the redirect washington.mysite.com/*(anything) to my-site.com/washington

Any suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?washington\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/washington [R=301,L]
```

In your `RewriteRule` you have `/$1` which matches the `(.*)` wildcard set of parentheses. This is why you're getting the path from the old URLs appended.

I combined your 2 `RewriteCondition`'s, making the `(www\.)` match optional with `?`.

The `[NC]` flag is the [`nocase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) flag.

To clear the querystring, append `?` to the end of the rewrite URL

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?washington\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/washington? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Awesome. This appears to be redrecting now to the correct page. However it still appends the ?query to the URL http://www.mysite.com/washington?washington-attractions&CatID=17 Any way of stripting this out so it doesn't confuse the user?